# Oracle 11g SQL loader, time format issue

Tags: oracle11g, sql-loader, time-format

I am trying to load a .csv file using SQL loader. I get this error message on a column that should store time column:

```
column TIME.ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

In my .csv file time has the format `HH:MM:SS` but I can't understand why Oracle does not recognise it.

Using the command `select * from nls_session_parameters;` I see that the default time format is `HH24.MI.SSXFF`. I tried to change the time separator in my csv file but I got the same error result.

I have a very simple control file, that looks like below.

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE Cycling_Accidents0512.csv
INTO TABLE CYCLING_ACCIDENTS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

(ID,
ACC_ID,
OSGB_EASTING,
OSGB_NORTHING,
WGS_LONG,
WGS_LAT,
POLICE_FORCE,
ACC_SEVERITY,
NUM_VEI,
NUM_CAS,
ACC_DATE,
DAY_WEEK,
TIME,
LOC_AUTH_DIS,
LOC_AUTH_HIGH,
FST_ROAD_CLASS,
FST_ROAD_NUMBER,
ROAD_TYPE,
SPEED_LIMIT,
JUNCT_DETAIL,
JUNCT_CONTROL,
SND_ROAD_CLASS,
SND_ROAD_NUM,
PED_HUM,
PED_PHY,
LIGHT_COND,
WEATH_COND,
ROAD_SUR_COND,
SPEC_COND,
CARR_HAZARDS,
URB_RUR,
POLICE_ATT,
LSOA_ACC_LOC,
VEI_TYPE)
```

If someone of you can help me to modify the control file in order to make the time format acceptable to Oracle, that would be appreciated. I tried to look up on other web resources but I haven't found anything that could help.

Thanks!

Comment: What data type is your `TIME` column? Oracle doesn't have a time-only type, so presumably it is actually a `DATE` type, or possibly `TIMESTAMP`. Either way the column would have a date part, even if you ignore it. So if the data only has the time you'd need to comvert it - how depends on the data type though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned querying the session NLS parameters, but the value you showed appears to be `NLS_TIME_FORMAT`, [which is only used internally](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/dynviews_2075.htm#sthref3315).

Oracle doesn't have a time-only type, so your field is presumably actually a `DATE` type (or possibly `TIMESTAMP`). The values in the column will have a date part, even if you ignore it.

SQL*Loader will use `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to interpret the data file value for a `DATE` field. If that is `DD/MM/YYYY` then it would liberally interpret a value like `22:41:17` as the 22nd day of the 41st month - hence your error - in the year 17.

You can specify the date format model in the control file:

```
TIME DATE 'HH24:MI:SS',
```

The value in the table would have that time, on the first day of the current month.

---

The SQL*Loader documentation does [refer to a `TIME` data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_field_list.htm#i1016161) which I have never seen used, and I can't find any references to it anywhere, including MOS. A quick bit of experimentation hasn't helped. If I make the control file entry:

```
TIME TIME,
```

... then the record is rejected with `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. The log file also shows the data type as `DATETIME HH24.MI.SSXFF`, which looks related to the `NLS_TIME_FORMAT` value. I haven't found a way to make it accept that. If I change the column definition from `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP` then I get a different error, `ORA-00904: "TO_TIME": invalid identifier`, which is even stranger. It almost looks like these data types are defined in SQL*Loader for future use. ([This discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/353973?tstart=0) suggests they thought about adding `TIME` as a database type in 10g, but obviously can't verify that. And this is in the SQL*Loader reference at least back to 9i).

Comment: I made it, it was just a matter of specifying the correct date format in the ctl file. Thank you very much for the explanation, complete and concise.